# HDFS /tmp filesystem is filling up rapidly and expected to cause outage

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, cloudera

In our Hadoop cluster (Cloudera distribution), we recently found that Hive Job is started by user create a 160 TB of files in '/tmp' location and it almost consumed remaining HDFS space and about to cause an outage. Later we troubleshoot and kill the particular job as we are unable to reach the user who started this job.

So now my question is could we able to set an alert for '/tmp' location if anyone created huge files or we need to restrict the users using HDFA quota. Please share if you have any other suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set and manage quota for a directory by using the below set of commands

```
    hdfs dfsadmin -setQuota <N> <directory>...<directory>

    hdfs dfsadmin -clrQuota <directory>...<directory>

    hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota <N> <directory>...<directory>

    hdfs dfsadmin -clrSpaceQuota <directory>...<directory>
```

> *where N is the Number of bytes you want to set

[Reference Link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsQuotaAdminGuide.html)

[Helpful article](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/03/28/hadoop-space-quotas-hdfs-block-size-replication-and-small-files/)

Hope this helps your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can also manage resources from Cloudera Manager in Yarn resource pool from the processing side. You can limit max cores and memory allocated to each user or service running on your cluster.